# ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In the show (html) page I have this

```
<% if  @movie.views_count > 150 && @movie.ratings_chart_last_days(30) < 4 %>
    You are in the first 3 positions
<% end %>
```

and in movie.rb I have this

```
  def ratings_chart_last_days(number_of_days)
    subset = Movie.where('movies.created_at >= ?', number_of_days.days.ago)
    @ratings_chart_last_days ||= chart_position(:ratings_abs, subset)
  end
```

But I have this report:

undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass

the ratings_chart_last_days method is returning nil. Then when it tries to do a < comparison it tries to execute the < method. NilClass doesn't support that method.

**How to solve?!**

EDITED

Chart_position code

```
module Chartable
  def chart_position(attribute, start_query = nil)
    attribute = self.class.connection.quote_column_name(attribute.to_s)
    partition = partition_by(start_query || self.class.all, attribute)
    self.class.from(partition, :s).select('s.id, s.position')
        .find_by('s.id = ?', id).try(:position)
  end

  private

  def partition_by(chain, attribute)
    chain
      .select('id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ('\
              "ORDER BY #{attribute} DESC, created_at DESC"\
              ') as position')
  end
end
```

Comment: Ensure that `ratings_chart_last_days` never returns `nil`

Comment: Can you please paste the code for chart_position too?

Comment: @SamyKacimi added

Answer (score 0):

Since your method `ratings_chart_last_days` might return `nil`, you can change it to:

```
def ratings_chart_last_days(number_of_days)
  subset = Movie.where('movies.created_at >= ?', number_of_days.days.ago)
  @ratings_chart_last_days ||= chart_position(:ratings_abs, subset)
  @ratings_chart_last_days ||= 0 # Just added
end
```

Comment: @ratings_chart_last_days ||= 0  ?

Because I'm noting that I'm having this issue with movies added August 19, 2019...

Comment: just noted that I have this issue in a Movie that has ratings_abs negative ( -0.6). With your solution I haven't the bug but this game has position 0 (on the top)

Comment: No so much. because now the Movie with the lowest ratings_abs is in the top position...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your intent is here but if you're only looking at movies created in the last 30 days and you have none, I suspect `chart_position` method might return `nil`?

You could either force it to be considered in the top three positions or force it to be considered unranked, your choice.  To include it in the the top position, return `0` otherwise return `Float::INFINITY`

```
def ratings_chart_last_days(number_of_days)
  @ratings_chart_last_days ||= {}
  return @ratings_chart_last_days[number_of_days] if @ratings_chart_last_days[number_of_days].present?
  subset = Movie.where('movies.created_at >= ?', number_of_days.days.ago)
  @ratings_chart_last_days[number_of_days] ||= chart_position(:ratings_abs, subset) || Float::INFINITY
end
```

I've also changed your memoization... you were always returning `@ratings_chart_last_days` regardless of the `number_of_days` argument, so I've suggested that `@ratings_chart_last_days` should be a hash of all previously calculated results, indexed by `number_of_days`

Comment: just noted that I have this issue in a Movie that has ratings_abs negative ( -0.6)